# Can't Uninstall A Program (Openshot)

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, qt

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
Have checked other answers here and nothing is relevant. After I updated Openshot I had two different versions installed at the same time. I deleted one successfully but now the other won't uninstall. I assume some dependencies were taken out?

1. `sudo apt-get remove --autoremove openshot-qt`
2. `sudo apt-get purge openshot-qt`

and all similar variations claim that the program isn't installed, but obviously I can still open it and see it. There's nothing in snaplist as I installed it through terminal. In synaptic manager it doesn't seem to be installed.

EDIT:
The program was installed by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa 
sudo apt install openshot-qt python3-openshot
```

I tried to remove / purge etc by typing openshot-qt python3-openshot etc

Comment: What command was used to install it?

Comment: The only reason for that is that you did not use apt to install it.  I agree with @david question: how was it installed. Where is the executable? In /opt/ perhaps? If so look for the uninstaller in /opt/{dir_for_openshot}/

Comment: Check for snaps: `snap list`. Openshot is available as a snap.

Comment: What do you have for `which openshot; which openshot-qt` ?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openshot-qt python3-openshot` @David @Rinzwind @N0rbert  It wasn`t installed as a snap @user535733

Answer (score 1):

If `apt` tells you the program is not installed, then it not installed within the APT system. It is most likely installed as a snap package. Use

```
snap list
```

to see the software installed as a snap.

Use

```
snap remove <package>
```

to remove a snap package.

Comment: Was installed through apt and not snap.

Comment: I am not sure, but you are best placed to know for sure, of course. You may perhaps, in your question, want to show some terminal output of the remove commands you try. You actually did not inform us how you updated Openshot: perhaps edit your question and add some detail on that also. Someone asked you for the output of `which`... mind: we are not the ones sitting at your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Run it in the termina.

```
apt-cache policy openshot-qt
```

To see what "status" the packages are in, excluding packages with "status" ii. you can run the command:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep "^[^ii]"
```

rc - means that the package has been deleted, but some configuration files remain.
To select and delete these packages, you can run the command:

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
```

You may also use Ubuntu Snap store to remove software. Any software that appears as installed there can be removed, whether it is an APT package or a snap package. The software center uses the correct protocol behind the scenes.